# VS11 Graphics Debugger does not capture the actual final frame

Tags: c#, debugging, graphics, sharpdx

I am trying to understand the workings of the new Visual Studio 2012 Graphics Debugger by testing on a C# SharpDX powered project.

I am rendering a simple triangle.

[image: Application]

When capturing a frame with the graphics debugger, the output does not show the rendered triangle.

[image: Captured frame]

The Graphics Event List shows everything, including the triangle draw call. I can also step through the shaders used for rendering the triangle.

Any ideas of why the captured frames only show the initial color set when clearing the render target?